# Название шелушащихся частичек кожи

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называются части шелушащейся кожи, вообще омертвевшие слои ее? Что отдирает обладатель?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что отслаивается и осыпается - *чешуйки*.

https://medportal.ru/enc/dermatology/symptoms/188/